# Invoking a method at the end of Cocoa's main event loop

Tags: cocoa, events, loops

How would it be possible to invoke a method at the end of Cocoa's main event loop after each iteration?  I want to do the exact same thing that NSManagedObjectContext's -processPendingChanges does.  According to the documentation, "In AppKit-based applications, this method is invoked automatically at least once during the event loop (at the end of the loop)."  I need to do the same thing for one of my own methods.  Is this possible?  I've read documentation about NSRunLoop and NSApplication's -run method, but I haven't been able to find the solution to this problem.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can achieve what you want by installing a [`CFRunLoopObserver`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFRunLoopObserverRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001442). You can get the current `CFRunLoopRef` via `CFRunLoopGetCurrent()` or from an `NSRunLoop` via `-[NSRunLoop getCFRunLoop]`.